# Translations Editor Android

Tags: android, android-resources

В Translations Editor в некоторых строках стоит галочка Untranslatable, я ее убираю, закрываю editor, снова открываю и галочка опять стоит, переводы все есть.
Из-за этого не билдиться проект.
Что за мистика?

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему, в некоторых строках стоял `translatable="false"` из-за этого галочка не убиралась.